# Unable to return next() from controller ExpressJS + Typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I am trying to use Typescript to develop a new REST API.
I have a controller which looks something like this.

```
export default class AuthController {
  static async getRegisterController(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
  ): Promise<Response> {
    const vendorData: RegisterInput = {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      contactNo: req.body.contactNo,
      referralCode: req.body.referralCode,
    };

    const userWithEmail = await VendorData.getVendorWithEmail(vendorData.email);
    if (userWithEmail) {
      return next(new ConflictException('User with email already exists'));
    }

    const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(vendorData.password);
    vendorData.password = hashedPassword;

    const savedVendor = await VendorData.insertVendor(vendorData);
    const successResult = Result.success(savedVendor);
    return new ApiResponse(res, successResult).apiSuccess();
  }
}
```

However, I'm not able to return the `next()` function here as the return type clashes with the return type of the controller. An async function always returns a `promise`, but the `next` function returns of type `void`. However, I do need the next function to propagate my errors to the global error handling middleware to send an appropriate response.

EDIT:
I just want to stop execution after I call `next(err);`. Just `return;` after `next(err)` wouldn't work as `return;` returns `Promise<undefined>` from an async function which also doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found for now is to have your controller return `Promise<Response | undefined>`. Since the router doesn't care about the controller's return type, this is possible.